# Excel: Setup of validation in a VBA sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a sub to configure the validation from lists for different ranges of a table to simplify the looks of the main routine, I can find the correct form of the validator for input to the Formula1 argument. Can you help me?

```
 'in the main routine
  add_validation  Range.Columns("A"), range("types")
  add_validation  Range.Columns("C"), range("units") 
  ....

  'the sub 
  Sub add_validation(to_validate As Range, validator As Range)
      With to_validate
        With .Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=validator
        End With
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Range arguement isn't quite right and the Formula for the validation expects a string. Do this:

```
 'in the main routine
  add_validation  Columns("A:A"), "types" ' Columns is the range object, you don't need Range.Column
  add_validation  Columns("C:C"), "units" ' Your named range is accessed via a string for cell validation
  ....

  'the sub 
  Sub add_validation(to_validate As Range, validator As String)
      With to_validate
        With .Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & validator
        End With
    End With
    End Sub
```